# Making first iOS App work

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to learn building apps using iOS. I am using Xcode 6.4, and [the tutorial I was following](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5pzlbBnfYg) seems to accept using fun and override, but when I try it, it brings errors. I am connecting a protected page to my registration page like this.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    - (void)ViewDidAppear(animated: bool) {
        [self.PerformSegueWithIdentifier("LoginView", sender: self)];
    }

}

@end
```

Can someone please help me point out my error and a solution?

Comment: Why is the `viewDidAppear:` method inside the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method? Why is the `viewDidAppear:` method written in a different language than the rest of the code?

Comment: You are following a tutorial in Swift but have began a project with Objective-C as the default language.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy i have moved the ViewDidAppear method out of didReceiveMemoryWarning, but am still getting errors, and the language bit, i think i haven't changed the language at all, any help with the correct code will be appreciated

Comment: so what should i initiate and call first, am a newbie guys

Comment: You don't need to implement any method that doesn't have any code other than a call to super. So, if you're not adding any code to viewDidLoad or didReceiveMemoryWarning, just delete them.

Comment: Just move out ViewDidAppear Method from didReceiveMemoryWarning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Typically this isn't a general debugging service but you might like a foot up...

1. In Objective-C methods can't be declared inside other methods. They can in Swift
2. Swift code can't be smooshed up alongside Objective-C code.
3. Case is important in Swift and Obj-C so `PerformSegueWithIdentifier` is not the same as `performSegueWithIdentifier`

---

So the correct version of what you are trying to do is...

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginView" sender:self];
}

@end
```

Have fun and enjoy iOS dev.

Answer (score 3):

You can't insert on method definition in another one

In my opinion in some way you messed up Swift and Objective C code,
 your code should looks like :

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.


}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated]; 

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginView" sender:self];
}

@end
```

Answer (score -3):

Looks like youre just attempting to override the viewcontrollers viewDidAppear method. If that's the case, the method is in the wrong place (in your code, its nest inside didReceiveMemoryWarning

Try this:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL) animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.performSegueWithIdentifier("nameOfSeque", sender: self)];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: This answer is still mashing Swift dot syntax inside ObjC `[ self.performSegueWithIdentifier() ]`